# How do i return the value of an Array from snapshot closure and use it in prepare for segue?

Tags: swift, firebase, closures, snapshot

I'm trying to get the value of an Array outside the function.But as soon as the block for the snapshot ends the value of newArray gets empty.
I want to access the value of an Array even after the closure ends.
After passing the value from prepare for segue to the next View Controller the value is still empty.

```
var newArray = [Any]()
func getData(refe: String) -> [Any]{

    let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "MyURL").child("users/\(currUser!)/Questions/")
    ref.child("\(refe)").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with:{ snapshot in

        let enumerator = snapshot.children
        while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value{
            self.newArray.append(value as! Any)
        }
        print(self.newArray)
//This gives [test,test1,test2]

    })
    return newArray
// Here the Array is empty.
}
```

Actual Result: []

Expected Result: [test, test1, test2]

I also tried this.

```
    func getData(refe: String, completion: @escaping (([Any]) -> ())) {
    var newArray = [Any]()
        let currUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "MYURL").child("users/\(currUser!)/Questions/")
        ref.child("\(refe)").observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { snapshot in

            let enumerator = snapshot.children
            while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot, let value = rest.value{

                newArray.append(value)
            }

        completion(newArray)
    })
    }
```

and calling it in helper function

```
func getDataD() -> [Any]{
    let ref = getReference()
    var arr = [Any]()
    self.getData(refe: ref) { (array) in
        arr = array
// This gives [test,test1,test2]
    }
    return arr
// This gives []
}
```

After that calling the function in prepare for segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard let detailViewController = segue.destination as? HostOptionTableViewController
        else {
            return
    }
    detailViewController.ref = getReference()
    self.getData(refe: detailViewController.ref) { (array) in
        detailViewController.data = array
    }   
}   
}
```

Actual result of detailViewController.data after execution should be [test,test1,test2]
but it is []

Comment: You should call the api inside `HostOptionTableViewController`. Just pass the required parameters that are needed for the api. OR remove navigation using `segue`, implement the button tap event, make api call, once data is ready then push/present `HostOptionTableViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's too late to call `getData` inside `prepareForSegue` , This should be inside the action that navigates to the second vc

```
 self.getData(refe:yourRef) { array in   
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"segueName",sender:array)
 }   


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    guard let detailViewController = segue.destination as? HostOptionTableViewController
        else {
            return
    }
    detailViewController.ref = getReference() 
    detailViewController.data = sender as! [Model] // Model is type of array     
}
```

the request is asynchronous and the navigation will occur before getting the data